# Required Graph API Permissions to get my own instagram posts

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am completely lost as to what permissions I should apply for in App review for getting my own Instagram posts through Facebook's Graph API.

I did the basic steps for using the API: I made my Instagram account a business one, and linked it to my Facebook page, it seems that to use Instagram graph API I must apply for app review, which I want to do, except I don't know which permissions to apply for.

My only purpose is to retrieve my own account's photos/posts, there are so many permissions available to apply for, do I need all of these?

instagram_basic

instagram_content_publish

instagram_manage_comments

instagram_manage_insights

Or just some of them? Are there other permissions I need for my purpose?

I would appreciate any help, I've been losing my mind over this for over 2 weeks now, and I can't find any other answers that are *recent* or *relevant*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you just want to get the media objects of an IG user, then `instagram_basic` and `manage_pages` permission [will be sufficient](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/media#get-media).

However, if you also want to access the [insights data of your media](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media/insights) (e.g. impressions, reach, etc.) then you need the `instagram_manage_insights` permission as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It's been a struggle

Comment: @jojomim - if this answer solved your problem - I'd be glad if you could accept [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)